# Providing NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR to component which does not from outside

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have to use a component which does not have implemented `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` in reactive form.

Is it possible to inject from outside? Any example or tutorial will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reactiveForm is independient of if we has an input or a custom form control. if the component has a "input" and a "output" su can use some like. For input I want to say some that reflex the value in the component, for Output any "onChange" that return a value

```
<app-component [input]="myFormControl.get('mycontrol').value 
               (output)="myFormControl.get('mycontrol').setValue($event)">
</app-component>
```

simple example, a component that was a button

```
  <button (click)="click()">{{count}}</button>

  @Input('input') count: number;
  @Output('output') output = new EventEmitter<any>();
  click() {
    this.count++;
    this.output.emit(this.count)
  }
```

Comment: looks something I can try. But getting error as value accessfor is not present when I add  `formControlName`

Comment: The idea is not use formControlName nor [formControl]. The idea is change the value using myForm.get('myControl').setValue(...), I write a simple example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udaqbd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks for hack, it helped me to get out from problem i am currently facing. But still we are lacking lots of form feature with this strategy like validation, touch, untouch etc.

Comment: I supouse you always can make a custom form control with the component inside, Again another stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6frtc6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-control.ts